# IoC com Web Service

Tags: c#, web-service, injeção-de-dependência, simple-injector

Eu preciso criar um WS com IoC.

1. Eu criei um projeto novo Web com as dependências de Web API ;
2. Acrescentei um Web Service(asmx);
3. Instalei o SimpleInjector;

O código ficou assim :

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class WSI : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

            private readonly ICrypto _crypto;

            public WSI(ICrypto crypto)
            {
                _crypto = crypto;
            }

            [WebMethod]
            public string HelloWorld()
            {
                return _crypto.Encrypt("Hello World");
            }
    }
```

O arquivo de inicialização do SimpleInjector está da seguinte forma :

```
 public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

        InitializeContainer(container);

        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        container.Verify();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
            new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<ICrypto, Crypto>();
    }
```

Quando executo recebo o erro :

```
System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem par&#226;metros foi definido para este objeto.
em System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
em System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
em System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
em System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
em System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
em System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
em System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
em System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi seu problema, deve ser porque o WebService(asmx) não permite que tenham construtores, pois, sua implementação é via proxy(aquela que é adicionada como referencia para o Serviço no client) que é substituída.

Caso seja realmente necessário utilizar o SimpleInjector recomendo alterar a abordagem para WCF.

Maiores informações: [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/107015/Referenced-WebService-class-constructor-with-param)

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma. ;)